# Mmap() Segmentation Fault Error While Reading The Stored Valued

Tags: c, process, mmap

I'm writing a program in C and using mmap() for processes to return the calculation to their main process.

Here is the code:

```
int *results = mmap ( NULL, count*sizeof(int),
 PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0 );

for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
      pid_t pid = fork();
      if (pid == 0)
      {
         /// some calculations in the child.
         }
         
         // I save the result to ith element of mmap
         results[i] = calculation;
      }
      else{
         wait(NULL);
      }
      
   }
    
   // The following part arises an error called segmentation fault.
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
      printf(" results[%d] = %d.\n", i, results[i]);
   }
```

When I try to access the results, I get an error. How can I fix that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you're mapping file descriptor `0`. Is that *really* what you wanted to do (hint: no, it isn't)

Comment: @MarcusMüller but the website that I got the code from sets it to 0 and it seems it works. I'm confused. You can check the website if you want : https://linuxhint.com/using_mmap_function_linux/

Comment: "the website" is not a good source of truth. Documentation is!

Comment: You're also not checking the result from `mmap()`.  `mmap()` returns `MAP_FAILED` when it doesn't work, which likely happens here.  You should have copied that part of the code, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cite `man mmap`:

> **MAP_ANONYMOUS**
>
> The mapping is not backed by any file; its contents are initialized to zero.  The fd argument is ignored; however, some implementations require fd to be -1 if MAP_ANONYMOUS (or MAP_ANON) is specified, and portable applications should ensure this.